# (Typo in Sample Code) Using "change" instead of "child_changed" to monitor devices

Tags: firebase, nest-api

I was looking through nest's example code, and in the [javascript/smoke_alarm example](https://developer.nest.com/documentation/alert) they use `alarm.on('change', function(snapshot) {...}` instead of using `alarm.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {...}`.

I don't see any documentation for `'change'` in the [firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/on.html), and it raises an error when I use it:

```
  Error: Query.on failed: First argument must be a valid event type: "value",  
  "child_added", "child_removed", "child_changed", or "child_moved".
```

Is this just a bug in the sample code, and it should really read: `alarm.on('child_changed', function(snapshot) {...}`? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that, it is a typo. The [sample code](https://github.com/nestlabs/alert-jquery) has now been updated.

Due to the nature of HTML5 Notifications, it currently works best in Safari, but I also modified the sample to log events in a  for other browsers so you can focus on the Nest specific code.